# Автозапуск ASP.NET MVC приложений?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Есть статья по решению данной проблемы [Автозапуск ASP.NET приложений](https://habrahabr.ru/post/73272/), но у меня нету доступа к IIS на хостинге. Как можно разогреть сайт без доступа к IIS?

Comment: запустить периодический опрос некой страницы сайта (можно эту страницу сделать специально)

Comment: @Konst это что-то на подобии таких ресурсов https://uptimerobot.com/ ?

Comment: да, возможно. сам не использовал

Comment: @Konst А есть какая-то возможно это сделать с программной стороны?

Comment: можете написать свой сервис, который будет делать периодические запросы к вашему сайту